# polar curves - Why do we reflect when $r$ is negative

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I've been looking for a answer to why we reflect the angle whenever the length "$r$" is negative.

Why does this change the sign for $r$, when adding $180$ degrees to the angle $\theta$?

It makes sense for me how the sign might change when rotating a trigonometric functions. Like adding $\pi$ to $\sin{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ i.e  $\sin{\frac{5\pi}{2}}$ will give me a positive value for $\sin(x)$

I've tried using the the definition for

$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, but i'm a little stuck and have yet to find a answer.

Comment: Going backwards by $5$ units from the origin is the same as going forwards by $5$ units, and then rotating $180º$.

Comment: @TobyMak Hmm. it is hard to visualize. How would it look mathematically?

Comment: It's simply the fact that $r\exp(i(\theta+\pi))=r\exp(i\pi)\exp(i\theta)=-r\exp(i\theta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you’re in a car that’s pointed east. Now travel in reverse for a distance $r$. Your final location can be expressed in polar coordinates as $(-r,0)$. On the other hand, you can instead turn the car around so that it faces west and then drive *forward* the same distance. This is expressed in polar coordinates as $(r,\pi)$. Either way, you end up in the same spot.

Algebraically, this is a straightforward consequence of the identities $$-\cos\theta = \cos(\theta+\pi) \\ -\sin\theta = sin(\theta+\pi).$$

Comment: Sorry for not responding earlier. I was more thinking how it goes in hand with the conversion. since $x^2 + y^2 = r^2 $ then it should not ever be possible for r to be negative. Irreverant of which quadrant it might be in it should be positive considering both x and y are squared.

Comment: If you’re starting from $x^2+y^2=r^2$, you’ve already got to consider two possible values for $r$ (unless $x=y=0$, of course).

Comment: Is it because $r= +-\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$?

Comment: Yes. However, look at the polar to Cartesian conversion instead: for $r\ge0$, we have $(-r)\cos\theta = r\cos(\theta+\pi)$ and similarly for $y$, so you get the same Cartesian coordinates with a negative $r$ that you do for a positive $r$ and the angle turned by $\pi$.

Comment: I see. But if it allows for negative values for r, why do we bother converting it? Is it because we want to treat "r" as a measure of length?